# Casting NSArray to NSMutable Array in swift 2.0

Tags: swift, parse-platform, nsmutablearray

I'm getting this console output when i try to insert nsarray objects to a mutable swift array. Code works fine but at the end, it is throwing an error. Please help me resolve this error.

```html
Successfully retrieved 3 scores.
Optional("HmEbbowtxW")
<Events: 0x7b08bdf0, objectId: HmEbbowtxW, localId: (null)> {
    CreatedBy = "<PFUser: 0x7b02ed10, objectId: 04jp1ZeBn6>";
    EventDescription = test;
    EventName = test;
}
Optional("97BzKUxFdE")
<Events: 0x7b08cae0, objectId: 97BzKUxFdE, localId: (null)> {
    CreatedBy = "<PFUser: 0x7b02ed10, objectId: 04jp1ZeBn6>";
    EventDescription = fg;
    EventName = gfg;
}
Optional("QDHkg5tiUw")
<Events: 0x7b08cf80, objectId: QDHkg5tiUw, localId: (null)> {
    CreatedBy = "<PFUser: 0x7b02ed10, objectId: 04jp1ZeBn6>";
    EventDescription = asdasdasd;
    EventName = sdsd;
}
Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayI' (0x228e164) to 'NSMutableArray' (0x228e1c8).
```

This is my code

```html
 let query = PFQuery(className:"Events")
        query.whereKey("CreatedBy", equalTo:PFUser.currentUser()!)
        
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects, error) -> Void in
           
            if error == nil {
                // The find succeeded.
                print("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
                // Do something with the found objects
                if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                    for object in objects {
                        
                        self.eventtimelineData.addObject(object)
                        print(object.objectId)
                        print(object.description)
                    }
                    
                    let array:NSArray = self.eventtimelineData.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects
                    self.eventtimelineData = array as! NSMutableArray
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                    
                }
                
                
            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To convert an `NSArray` to an `NSMutableArray`, call `mutableCopy()` and cast to `NSMutableArray`:

```
let a: NSArray = [1, 2.5, "hello"]

let b = a.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray

b.addObject(17)  // b is [1, 2.5, "hello", 17]
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot cast from NSArray to NSMutableArray. You need to create a new mutable array from it:

```
self.eventtimelineData = array.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
```